# Use response result outside the subscribe resulting to undefined in Angular6

Tags: typescript, angular6

Good day,

I'm new with using Angular6, I'm having a trouble because I want to get the value response result inside the subscribe and use it outside the subscribe.

Here are my codes:

```
name: string;

constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

myMethod(){
    this.myService.getName().subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.name = response.name;
    }, error => {
        console.log(`Something went wrong`);
    });

    console.log(this.name);
}
```

To add up,

Here is my sample service:

```
myService(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${apiUrl}names/`);
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm having `undefined` error on my `console.log(this.name)` I already using Observable on my angular service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I've read that. But it doesn't help me though

Comment: which one @joseatchang?

Comment: Sorry nvm, I see fat arrows don't know why. But you have none. When you print this.name is `undefined` because it haven't been resolve the response yet, so you will get undefined

Comment: oh and how to fix it?

Comment: By reading the duplicate and the linked questions in it. _"tl;dr"_: You can not "fix" it. You will have to adjust your code to work with the asynchronous behavior.

Comment: Do you have a sample code sir?

Comment: I'm using observable already